# ReactJS : Immutable.js : merge two Json objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I'm using React, Redux & immutable. I tried to merge two Json objects, data and expected result is given below,

```
obj1 = 
{id: 1, first_name: "abc", surname: "def", children: ["kid1", "kid2"]}

obj2 = 
{first_name: "abc", surname: "def", email: "abc.def@gmail.com", mobile: ""}

mergedObj = {id: 1, first_name: "abc", surname: "def", email: "abc.def@gmail.com", Mobile: "",  children: ["kid1", "kid2"]}
```

If data is not available on obj1, it should be taken it from obj2.

I tried using immutable merge as outlined below,

```
import Immutable, {merge} from "immutable";
const mergedObj = merge(Immutable.fromJS(obj2), Immutable.fromJS(obj1));
console.log(mergedObj)
```

Result is same as obj2, essentially, merge is not happening,

```
{first_name: "abc", surname: "def", email: "abc.def@gmail.com", mobile: ""}
```

Comment: You're merging two *plain objects* (a.k.a. POJOs). "JSON" refers to a string representation of those. (being pedantic for the 2nd time on this page, sorry). Anyway, upvoted question for being clear and legitimate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do merge using javascript spread operator which is introduced in ES6 onwards.

```
var obj1 = {id: 1, first_name: "abc", surname: "def", children: ["kid1", "kid2"]}

var obj2 = {first_name: "abc", surname: "def", email: "abc.def@gmail.com", mobile: ""}

var mergedObj = {...obj1,...obj2};
```

Comment: For more info about spread operator here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-spread-operator/

Comment: For the sake of pedantry, the *spread operator for object literals* has been introduced in ES2018 (so not available in ES6)

Comment: Perfect Solution for combining two JSON Objects !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

**The docs seem to indicate you are using immutable.merge() correctly.**

Sadly, this feature seems broken, as one can see on [their live example](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/merge).

I would advise to submit an issue/pull-request to get this fixed, but it seems like [immutable is now essentially **unmaintained**](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js/issues/1689) -- the repo sits with 26 open pull requests, and none was merged in the last month.

---

**Anyway, I would say that can do just fine with ES6+ JS.** Immutable was kind of a must-have before that, because JS did not offer adequate tools out-of-the-box for that paradigm.

If that's an option (or even if it's not, the following will work as intended), consider @AlwinJose's suggestion of using the [spread syntax for object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Syntax), available since ES2018:

> ```
> var mergedObj = {...obj1,...obj2};
> ```

(performs a *shallow merge*, just like [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign))

Comment: Hugo, Thanks for your reply. I will raise an issue. For now i am going ahead with ES6 solution

Comment: *\*cough\* ES2018 \*cough\**

Comment: It's unlikely to be fixed anytime soon, but if you want to raise the issue go ahead :) at least it will be documented

Answer (score 1):

exampleData=

```
        const json1 = [
            {id: 1, test: 1},
            {id: 2, test: 2},
            {id: 3, test: 3},
            {id: 4, test: 4},
            {id: 5, test: 5}
        ];

        const json2 = [
            {id: 3, test: 6},
            {id: 4, test: 7},
            {id: 5, test: 8},
            {id: 6, test: 9},
            {id: 7, test: 10}
        ];
```

example1=

```
        const finalData1 = json1.concat(json2).reduce(function (index, obj) {
            index[obj.id] = Object.assign({}, obj, index[obj.id]);
            return index;
        }, []).filter(function (res, obj) {
            return obj;
        });
```

example2=

```
        let hashData = new Map();

        json1.concat(json2).forEach(function (obj) {
            hashData.set(obj.id, Object.assign(hashData.get(obj.id) || {}, obj))
        });

        const finalData2 = Array.from(hashData.values());
```

I recommend second example , it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with POJOs and want to end with a POJO, I recommend using object spread syntax (or `Object.assign`) as mentioned above. There's no need to use Immutable in that case.

If you want to use Immutable, and you know that `obj1` and `obj2` are objects, you can call `Map(obj2).merge(obj1)` instead, which definitely works. (Based on widespread usage in our codebase.)

Otherwise, the docs claim that you can call `Immutable.merge` with POJOs, so you might have better luck with `Immutable.merge(obj2, obj1)`, leaving out the calls to `Immutable.fromJS`.